# How to display an custom ValidationMessage for a list property

Tags: validation, .net-core, blazor

I'm having some trouble displaying a custom validation error message inline in a Blazor edit form.

On the model, we have a custom ValidationAttribute (`OptionFieldsNotEmpty`) which checks that a list is populated.

```
class Field {
[OptionFieldsNotEmpty]
public List<OptionFieldViewModel> Options { get; set; }
}
```

In the razor page I have a tried to use the standard ValidationMessage but nothing shows for the markup below (`OptionEditor` is a custom component rendering a list of inputs)

```
<OptionEditor OptionFields="@Field.Options"/>
<ValidationMessage For="() => Field.Options"/>
```

The custom validation definitely works but but the ValidationMessage doesn't show inline where I'd like it to. The message does appear in the ValidationSummary.

It seems like because Field.Options isn't actually bound to a form input, the framework doesn't know where to render it.

Does anyone know if this is possible or should I fall back to a ValidationSummary?

Answer (score 1):

The Blazor "EditContext" is a bit of a contradition: simplistic in it's concept and complex in it's implementation.  `ValidationSummary` is a case in point.  `For` defines an expression that it then needs to jump through hoops backwards to decode.  Lots of CPU cycles wasted doing something that doesn't really need doing.

Here's an alternative `ValidationMessage` that simply accepts the `Model` and `FieldName` as parameters.  No `For`: it constructs the `FieldIdentifier` based on the `Model` and `FieldName` provided.  It's a lift of the `ValidationSummary` code without the expression untaggling and refection.

In your case just put in a break at a convenient place and find the `Model` and `FieldName` for your error message to enter as parameters.

```cs
@implements IDisposable

@foreach (var message in CurrentEditContext.GetValidationMessages(_fieldIdentifier))
{
    <div class="validation-message">
        @message
    </div>
}

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] EditContext CurrentEditContext { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public  object Model { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public string FieldName { get; set; } = default!;

    private readonly EventHandler<ValidationStateChangedEventArgs>? _validationStateChangedHandler;
    private FieldIdentifier _fieldIdentifier => new FieldIdentifier(this.Model, this.FieldName);
    private EditContext? _previousEditContext;

    public CustomValidationMessage()
        => _validationStateChangedHandler = (sender, eventArgs) => StateHasChanged();

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if (CurrentEditContext == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{GetType()} requires a cascading parameter " +
                $"of type {nameof(EditContext)}. For example, you can use {GetType()} inside " +
                $"an {nameof(EditForm)}.");

        if (CurrentEditContext != _previousEditContext)
        {
            DetachValidationStateChangedListener();
            CurrentEditContext.OnValidationStateChanged += _validationStateChangedHandler;
            _previousEditContext = CurrentEditContext;
        }
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {}

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        DetachValidationStateChangedListener();
        Dispose(disposing: true);
    }

    private void DetachValidationStateChangedListener()
    {
        if (_previousEditContext != null)
            _previousEditContext.OnValidationStateChanged -= _validationStateChangedHandler;
    }
}
```

To demo I've modified `WeatherForecast`:

```cs
public class WeatherForecast
{
    public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
    [Range(-40, 60, ErrorMessage = "Temperature must be between -40 and 60.")]
    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    public string? Summary { get; set; }
}
```

And then a demo page:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<EditForm Model=this.model>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <InputNumber class="form-control" @bind-Value=this.model.TemperatureC />
    <CustomValidationMessage Model="model" FieldName="TemperatureC" />

    <div class="m-2 p-2 bg-light">
        <ValidationSummary />
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private WeatherForecast model = new();
}
```

For reference the `ValidationMessage` code is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/ValidationMessage.cs)

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for this. I haven't used your code but your link to the ValidationMessage github put me on the path to find the "built in" solution.

Answer (score 1):

After looking into the dotnet core code I saw that instead of using `ValidationMessage` you can use the `ValidationSummary` with a `Model` parameter set to show "inline" errors at a model level:

`<ValidationSummary Model="Field"/>`

[image: Model level error message displayed inline]